# Page crawler index in kentico is not showing the content in the results

Tags: search, indexing, kentico

I'm trying to show the results of a page crawler index the results are fine but the problem is that when I try to show the content value is empty I'm using  OnHtmlToPlainText method in a class for filter content.
This is the code of the transformation

```
 <div class="content">
        <%#SearchHighlight(HTMLHelper.HTMLEncode(TextHelper.LimitLength(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HTMLHelper.StripTags(CMS.Base.Web.UI.ControlsHelper.RemoveDynamicControls(GetSearchedContent(DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(Eval("CONTENT"), ""))), false, true, " ", "@", "")), 280, "...")), "<span style='background-color: #FEFF8F'>", "</span>")%><br />
 </div><!--  content -->
```

this is the backend code

```
public class CustomSearchCrawlerModule : CMS.DataEngine.Module
{

    private void OnGetPageContent(object sender, DocumentSearchEventArgs e)
    {

    SearchField sf=new SearchField();
    sf.FieldName = "CONTENT";
    sf.Value = e.Content;

    string content = e.Content;
    e.SearchDocument.AddSearchField(sf);
    }

}
```

Any advice , please

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code for template and works fine for me. There is no need to add new field for content because that field already exist, unless you have some custom logic there. If you have it, maybe you should check that logic first. It could cause that e.Content is empty string already. You can try this syntax as well:

```
e.SearchDocument.Add("CONTENT", e.Content, true, true);
```

Comment: I tried with the default Content field, but it is not showing the content that's why I tried with a custom but it's not showing anything either. can be a settings or roles thing?

Comment: What is the page type for the page that's been crawled? If you go to the page type > select that page type > search field tab. What's mapped to Content? If this page is totally generated dynamically, then there is no DocumentContent to be mapped to Content. You can choose something like metadata Description to map to Content and you can use the meta data tab to enter the teaser.

Comment: yeah, that is what happens the content field is null because is dynamic content do you know if is any way to add the whole document-content value in the metadata of the description? @Rui

Comment: You need to populate the metadata manually and it should be something meaningful than dynamically generated random stuff. Dynamic content should not be used for teaser. In the transformation, the "Content" is for teaser display only, not for index.